# Tailwind hiding even though directive to show on lg

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following code using TailwindCSS 2:

```
    <div class="hidden lg:inline-block">
    <div class="bg-white text-sm w-full pl-4 pr-4 rounded shadow-xl inline-flex flex-grow items-center justify-between mt-4 ">
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" role="button" >development news</a></div>
        @if (Auth::user()->developer == 1 )
            <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >developer menu</a></div>
        @endif
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >URLs</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >how do I?</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >view sitemap</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >version</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >toggle menu items</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >highlight menu items</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >about White Label Site</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >other sites</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >newsletters</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >uploads</a></div>
        <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >maintenance & timeout</a></div>
        @if (Auth::user()->developer == 1 )
            <div><a class="{{ $btn }}" href="#" >library</a></div>
        @endif           
    </div>
</div>
```

My requirement is to only show this code if it is not a small screen, but it is showing it on small screens.

Help appreciated!